# VBA hex value generation from an array

Tags: vba, excel

i have a few checklist box in my excel sheet (say A-F i.e., caption of checkbox),based on the enabling of check list, i have to generate hex value...does the below code will do it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim SegArray(15) As Integer

 For i = 0 To 13

     If CheckBox(i).Value = True Then
         SegArray(i) = 1
     Else
         SegArray(i) = 0
     End If

 Next i

 hex_value = Hex(SegArray())

 MsgBox "0x" & hex_value

End Sub
```

i got an error:

> compile error: sub or function isnt defined

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your function

- the `CheckBox`'s are not an array.  They cannot be referenced as `ChecklBox(i)`
- The first checkbox placed will be named `CheckBox1` not `CheckBox0`
- the `Hex` function converts a decimal number, not an array, or a binary number

Heres your function reworked to address these issues

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Const num_of_checkboxes = 14

    Dim SegArray() As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dec_value As Long
    Dim hex_value As String

    ReDim SegArray(1 To num_of_checkboxes)
    dec_value = 0

    For i = 1 To num_of_checkboxes
        If Me.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & i).Object.Value Then
            dec_value = dec_value + 2 ^ (i - 1)
        End If
    Next i
    hex_value = Hex(dec_value)
    MsgBox "0x" & hex_value
End Sub
```

Assumes CheckBox1 is the least significant bit

Comment: hi chris, the above code didnt work as i expected. If i select i , k, l,n check box it should give the hex value as 0x002D but it is giving 0x2D00 which isnt expected.

Comment: Check the order of your check boxes.  As I said in the answer, the code required the checkbox numbers to be in bit order, starting at the least significant bit.

Comment: sorry to say, its giving the same result as 0x2D00 & not 0x002D. The 'I' checkbox NAME is CHECKBOX9 ... as 'N'corresponds to CHECKBOX14.                                                             Also, if i select A ,B,C ,D,E,F check Boxes then it should give 0x3F00 but it is giving 0x3F only.HOw can i modify the code?

Comment: That not making sense. The check box names should be CheckBox1, CheckBox2, ... , checkBox14.  If thats not the case you need to either rename the check boxes or modify the code to use the names you have

Comment: it is  CheckBox1, CheckBox2, ... , checkBox14 only, in my last comment i wrongly mentioned it as CHECKBOX9. Actually it is like wat u said, CheckBox1, CheckBox2, ... , checkBox14.

Comment: I think you might be counting from the wrong end.  If you select only CheckBox1, what value do you get? (it should be 0x1 since it is the least significant bit)

Comment: yaa. right. if i selct checkbox1,it is giving 0x1.                                                                   say if i select A,B,C,D,E,F it should give 0x3F00 & not 0x3F. similarly, if i select I,K,L,N it should give 0x002D & not 0x2D00.IF the position of the value changes,then the value interpreted is wrong.

Comment: hi chris, if a checkbox1 is selected then it should store the value as 1 in array & in a similar way if the checkbox2 isnt selected then it should store it as zero. For Eg.,we will take the same ex., if we select A,B,C,D,E,F is selected then in array it could contain 111111 for A-F & the rest checkboxes be zero (00000000),the actual arrayshould be 11111100000000.Then if we convert this bin to hex it would be 0x3F00. In this way, we can avoid the problem which i mentioned in above comment.Is it possible to write a code for this?